# Is there a way to make `python -q` the default behaviour for the python interpreter?

Tags: python

I recently learned that if you start the python interpreter with the `-q` parameter, it will omit version and copyright and show you directly the prompt.

```
$ python3 -q
>>>
```

Is there a way to make this the **default** behavior? I could always just `alias python=python -q` in my `.bashrc` but that would be my last resort, I'm rather looking for a way to configure python.

Comment: If you do this, please remember to turn it off when generating content for others to consume. When debugging other peoples' screenshots or transcripts, that header is extremely useful.

Comment: Why would you consider creating an alias as a last resort? That's a bash feature that was created exactly for that use-case.

Comment: Reading the CPython source, I don't see anything other than the command-line argument. There are hooks for someone implementing their own Python repl or other frontend to use to configure it, but that doesn't help if you want to use the stock one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like it: see the output of `python3 --help`, which says:

```
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
...
-q     : don't print version and copyright messages on interactive startup
```

There is no environment variable corresponding to the `-q` flag; c.f. other flags such as `-v`, which specify an environment variable that serves the same purpose:

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
```

So a shell alias is probably the way to go if this is important enough to you, though you don't have to give it the same name; I might go with something like `py3i` for "Python 3 Interactive", leaving the existing `python3` (or `python` for Python 2 or on Windows) command unchanged.